# Real Analysis For Beginners

Tags: real-analysis

What is the derived set for $S=\left\{\dfrac n {n+1}\middle|n\in\Bbb N\right\}$?

I am not able to justify the limit $1.$

There's got to be some way.

Comment: try showing for $n$ sufficiently large that  $|\frac{n}{n+1}-1|<\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon >0$ just do a bit of algebraic manipulations

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  Note that if $N\gt\dfrac1{\epsilon}$ then $\left|\dfrac N{N+1}-1\right|<\epsilon$

Comment: Can you plz solve in a page and post the photo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To justify that $1$ is a limit point for $S=\left\{\dfrac n {n+1}\middle|n\in\Bbb N\right\}$,

note that for all $\varepsilon\gt0,$ if $N\gt\dfrac1\varepsilon$, then $\left|\dfrac N{N+1}-1\right|=\dfrac1{N+1}\lt\dfrac1N\lt\varepsilon$.